# Dynamically need an image redirect to an external url in react

Tags: reactjs

Here's my code everything is fine but
image getting redirected to localhost:3000/www.xyz.com
I want it to be redirected to something like [www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com) directly without a home directory

```
{verticalSlide.map( (item) => ( 
<NavLink to={`${item.link}`}  >
<img src={item.image} alt="/"/>
</NavLink>
))}
```

Comment: what do you get when you console.log item.image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use NavLink, instead directly open url with help of window object

```
{verticalSlide.map( (item) => ( 
  <img onClick={() => window.open(item.link, '_blank')} src={item.image} alt="/"/>
))}
```